# how to check div is last child from parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

In **Jquery** or **JavaScript** have a function like `.hasNext()`. I have the code:

```
function showArrowClick() {
   var activeContact = $('.contact.white_bg');
   activeContact.removeClass('white_bg');
   activeContact.next().addClass('white_bg');
}
```

and parent div is

```
<div class="list">
     <div class="contact white_bg all_contacts">All</div>
     <div class="contact">Contact1</div>
     <div class="contact">Contact2</div>
</div>
```

After click last div need to do **something**. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify if there is any element when you're trying to select it:

```
function showArrowClick() {   
   var activeContact = $('.contact.white_bg');

   if(activeContact.next('div.contact').length > 0) {
     activeContact.removeClass('white_bg');
     activeContact.next().addClass('white_bg');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want `:last-child`.

```
$('a').click(function() {

  $('.list .contact:last-child').doSomething();

});
```

Edit:

Or if you meant clicking the last child itself...

```
$('.list .contact:last-child').click(function() {

  $(this).doSomething();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `.next()` to check. [read more](http://api.jquery.com/next/). Use it with the `.length` method to get to check if there are any more item on the DOM.

Sample code

```
alert($('div.contact').next().length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Something Like

```
$('.list').find("div.contact:last").addClass('white_bg');
```

**Second**

```
$('.list .contact:last-child').addClass('white_bg');
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [$.fn.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the:last-child selector

```
$(".list div:last-child").on('click', function(){
//Do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function showArrowClick() {
   var activeContact = $('.contact.white_bg');
   var index = activeContact.index();
   if (index === $(".contact.white_bg").children().length - 1) {
     // Current seleceted is the last div
    }
   activeContact.removeClass('white_bg');
   activeContact.next().addClass('white_bg');
}
```